# Postgres Query uses Bitmap index scan on GIN indexed item. Does not GIN use B-Tree internally?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, bitmap, query-planner, b-tree-index

From postgres docs on [GIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/gin-implementation.html) -

> Internally, a GIN index contains a B-tree index constructed over keys.

But in my use case, I see `Bitmap` indexes instead -

My Schema and Indexes are created as below.

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
    jdata jsonb NOT NULL,
    comments text NULL
);

CREATE INDEX idx_jdata ON customer USING gin (jdata jsonb_path_ops);
```

Say, inserted a 10K records. [sample prepared data](https://jsonformatter.org/42af5d)/ [alternate link](http://jsonblob.com/1057746685207527424)

```
explain analyze select jdata from  customer where jdata @> '{"supplier":{"id":"7f5644ca-f0d3-4f50-947b-9e3e38f7b796"}}'
```

Outpt -

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on file_set  (cost=2139.27..36722.32 rows=10744 width=18) (actual time=1.438..267.122 rows=4048 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (jdata @> '{"supplier": {"id": "7f5644ca-f0d3-4f50-947b-9e3e38f7b796"}}'::jsonb)
  Heap Blocks: exact=1197
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_jdata  (cost=0.00..2136.58 rows=10744 width=0) (actual time=1.214..1.214 rows=4048 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (jdata @> '{"supplier": {"id": "7f5644ca-f0d3-4f50-947b-9e3e38f7b796"}}'::jsonb)
Planning Time: 0.065 ms
Execution Time: 267.456 ms
```

(the query plan above is based on real output form postgres - i had to change table/column names)

**Why is `Bitmap` index created when a `GIN` index is created**

My Postgres DB version is **13.5**.

---

After looking at comment from @a-horse-with-no-name  -> I tried below

```
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
explain analyze
select * from pg_opclass where "oid"=10003;
SET enable_seqscan = ON;
```

and the output -

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Index Scan using pg_opclass_oid_index on pg_opclass  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=93) (actual time=0.015..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)|
  Index Cond: (oid = '10003'::oid)                                                                                              |
Planning Time: 0.060 ms                                                                                                         |
Execution Time: 0.027 ms                                                                                                        |
```

I see difference -
"Bitmap Index Scan **on** idx_jdata" *vs* "Index Scan **using** pg_opclass_oid_index **on pg_opclass**"

Does this mean anything important. Can some one add more details about the `using` vs `on` and the `on pg_opsclass`.

Comment: There is no bitmap index "created", what you are seeing is a "bitmap **scan**" which reads data from the index and keeps a bitmap of the data in memory.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - is the `explain` output bit messed.. should not it also include the index scan details. How can I figure out if its a in memory build up from the index.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - plz see my further addition to the question. Any thing you want to elaborate over `on` vs `using`.

Answer (score 2):

A GIN index can contain the same tuple pointer multiple times, listed under different tokens which the field is broken down into.  Those need to be de-duplicated to make sure it doesn't return duplicate rows where it should not, and the way GIN chooses to do this is by forcing it go through a bitmap index scan; which inherently deduplicates the pointers. It is not the index which is the bitmap, it is the scan which uses bitmaps. Any index can be used in a bitmap index scan, but GIN indexes can *only* be used in bitmap scans, due to the need to deduplicate.